# (Laravel 8) errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, laravel-8

I want to create a table that assists users to read the topics that order by categories; also, users select the categories that they want in order to see the interest topics associated with categories. For instance, when users go to BBC, they can see the topics that they want to see from categories.

---

**categories Table**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sports |
| 2 | Tech |

```php
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });

    }
?>
```

---

**users**

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fahad | f@f.com |
| 2 | Jhon | Jho@h.com |

```php
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

---

**category_user** -> piviot table

| id | user_id | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

```php
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**Category  -> Model**

```php
    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

---

**Error**

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `athar_db`.`category_user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `category_user` add constraint `category_user_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `cascade` (`id`))
```

Comment: you may choose to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem. :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Okay, Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the documentation first.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

> The `foreignId` method is an alias for `unsignedBigInteger` while the `constrained` method will use conventions to determine the table and column name being referenced. If your table name does not match Laravel's conventions, you may specify the table name by passing it as an argument to the `constrained` method:

The issue is that you're providing the **table name** as `'cascade'` instead of `'users'`.
i.e

```
//Should be...
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
//Instead of...
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('cascade');
```

Don't forget to correct the `'category_id'` as well.

If you really wish to apply `'cascade'` options, try:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
      ->constrained()
      ->onUpdate('cascade')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I have tried this way, and I was confused. However, now it’s clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

use the `cascadeOnDelete()` Method to define the cascade

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete()
```